# Xamarin IOS Binding library for WorldPayCSE

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, worldpay, xamarin.ios-binding

I need to make use of the worldPay CSE (Client side encryption) SDK (https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/clientsideencryption) for IOS and android within xamarin forms so I have created 2 Binding libraries. I have successfully created a wrapper for android and this is working fine but I am having an issue with IOS.

I downloaded https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-cse-lib-ios and followed the below tutorial on creating a binding library and mapping the API definitions using objective sharpie https://www.xamboy.com/2020/07/20/creating-a-xamarin-binding-library-for-ios-and-android-part-1/

I was able to build the solution and it appears to be creating the objects from the header files but when I run worldpayCSE.Encrypt(wpCardData, out NSEncryptError) method I get the following error:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
> Reason: -[NSTaggedPointerString isEmpty]: unrecognized selector sent
> to instance 0xff2d7cc5da80afba Native stack trace:    0   CoreFoundation
> 0x000000010b2ebfba __exceptionPreprocess + 242    1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x000000011c694ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
> 0x000000010b2fad2f +[NSObject(NSObject)
> instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0  3   CoreFoundation
> 0x000000010b2f04cf ***forwarding*** + 1455    4   CoreFoundation
> 0x000000010b2f27a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120    5
> Test3dsecureSolution.iOS            0x000000010a6d180a
> -[WPCardValidator validateNumber:withExpectedLength:] + 61    6   Test3dsecureSolution.iOS            0x000000010a6d18ba
> -[WPCardValidator validateMonth:] + 48    7   Test3dsecureSolution.iOS            0x000000010a6d153e -[WPCardValidator validate:] + 117   8
> Test3dsecureSolution.iOS            0x000000010a6d3b66 +[WorldpayCSE
> validate:] + 72   9   Test3dsecureSolution.iOS
> 0x000000010aa41089 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217     10  ???
> 0x00000001592f5e10 0x0 + 5791243792

It appears to be falling over on the validation method. However when I run the native demo project in xcode it works fine so Im pretty sure the issue isn't with the framework files and I suspect I maybe missing something

I have checked the API definitions and while 2 verify tags did flag. They appear to relate to GetPublic Key and GetJson. Both don't need to be exposed to xamarin IOS and appear to be red heron

I have pushed a copy of my solution onto git hub. The encryptionmethod is trigged from the button on the about page via the dependency service to the IOS implemenation ofthe WorldPayClient.cs

https://github.com/Law85/XamarinForms.WorldPayCSEBinding

Here is also the script I ran to generate the API definitions and strut
sharpie bind --output=WorldpayCSE --namespace=WorldpayCSE --sdk=iphoneos14.5  /Users/lukewinthorpe/Desktop/WorldPay/WorldpayCSE.framework/Headers/*.h -scope /Users/lukewinthorpe/Desktop/WorldPay/WorldpayCSE.framework/Headers

Any assistance anyone can throw my way would be appreciated.

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this if anyone needs it in the future. Ill check it into the repo. So it looks like I overlooked step 2 onthe world pay site

> Alternative: Manual installation To use the manual method:
>
> 1.Download and import WorldpayCSE.framework and openssl.framework into your project. Use the GitHub releases page for this.
>
> **2.In Xcode add -ObjC to Other Linker Flags from Build Settings.**

https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/clientsideencryption/ios-integration

On the properties section of both the Frameworks open.ssl and WorldPayCSE make sure you set the linker flags prop to -ObjC

Feel like an idiot but atleast its working :)